# how to redirect one html page to another using button click event in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am using angularjs directive to redirect another html page.i am writing click function inside directive but i am getting page name in alert box  not redirect to another html page.

sample.html:

```
<test1>
<button data-ng-click="click('/page.html')">Click</button>
</test1>
```

sample.js:

```
app.directive('test1',['$location', function(location) {
    function compile(scope, element, attributes,$location) {
         return{
             post:function(scope, element, iAttrs,$location) {
                 scope.click=function(path)
                 { 
                     alert("click"+path);
                     $location.path('/path');
                 };
             }
         };
        }

        return({
            compile: compile,
            restrict: 'AE',
        });

    }]);
```

i want to redirect page.html how to do this please suggest me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In html,

```
<button ng-click="redirect()">Click</button>
```

In JS,

```
$scope.redirect = function(){
  window.location = "#/page.html";
}
```

Hope it helps.....

Answer (score 8):

Would probably make a small modification.

inject $location and use:

```
$scope.redirect = function(){
  $location.url('/page.html');
}
```

The benefits of using $location over window.location can be found in the docs, but here's a summary as of (1.4.x)

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

[image]

If anyone knows how to make this redirect directly from the html in a cleaner way please let me know because I would prefer that sometimes over making a function in the controller...

Answer (score 1):

I have succeeded  navigation PAGE with below code in AngularJS.

```
$scope.click = function ()
{
    window.location = "/Home/Index/";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using material design button 'md-button', you could do this.

I have tried giving attribute href, assigned with the link path. The redirection works well.

This could be tried if it is only redirection and there are no other tasks to be done before redirection.

```
<test1>
  <md-button href="/page.html">Click</md-button>
</test1>
```