# How to redirect Page using ASP.net Angular js

Tags: asp.net, angular

I want to redirect to another page when I click on the valid button but i can not succeeded. I use Asp.NET Angular js. I created my function in my controller :

```
$scope.RedirectionUrl = function (urlConf) 
        $scope.urlConf = urlConf;

    }
```

in Redirect.chtml page i have :

```
@{
    var urlConf = Url.Action("PageConfiguration", "Common");
        urlConf = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(urlConf);
}

 <button ng-click="RedirectionUrl('@urlConf')" ng-if="selectedLeaf != null">{{ loadedFilter | i18n :'Valider':'Valider'}}</button>
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857822/how-to-redirect-one-html-page-to-another-using-button-click-event-in-angularjs

Comment: i refered to this ticket but i can't resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
     $scope.RedirectionUrl = function (urlConf) {
        document.location.href=urlConf;
    }
```